# Is there another more official theatrical term for “straight man”?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, theater

Thesauri provide “straight person”, “sidekick”, “second banana”, “feed” or “feeder”, “foil”, and “stooge”. We are curious if the theatrical community has a more formal or administrative term.

Comment: We theater people don't go in much for "formal or administrative terms". Old-fashioned terms from repertory theatres are "Charles-his-friend" and "juvenile lead".

Comment: A sidekick isn't necessarily a straight man/person: sometimes the lead role is the straight man role. Some comedy doesn't have a straight man role.

Comment: Functionally, none of the claimed "synonyms" mean what "straight man" stands for in theater. "Charles-his-friend" is a bit different, too, while "juvenile lead" is way, way irrelevant. Sadly though, I know of no other term for "straight man" in the arts because that's exactly what it is supposed to be, is totally self-explanatory and even sounds funny enough for the context.

Answer (score 3):

**Straight man** is the term that tends to be used for that role in the theatrical community. From the *[The Methuen Drama Dictionary of the Theatre](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tb-OAQAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA482&dq=theatrical%20dictionary%20AND%20%22straight%20man%22&pg=PA482#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, at the end of the entry for *stooge*:

> A **straight man**, the serious and sometimes bullying member of a two-man comedy act, differs from a stooge in being less of a victim.

The *stooge* is a related term, but note the way the dictionary distinguishes from a *straight man*: a *stooge* was an originally Vaudevillian performer who fed a smart alec and took a lot of abuse; a *straight man* keeps composure in the face of someone else's goofiness, and practices *deadpan* to elicit humor.

**Straight woman** is sometimes used as well, as seen in a [New York Times theater review](https://books.google.com/books?id=geRRHx3m9ZIC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA39&dq=%22straight%20woman%22%20theater&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Ms. Goldberg, whose presence is less frantic and more deliberately centered, is instead the sardonic **straight woman** to the chaos around her.

That said, note that **straight man** and **straight woman** also has a different meaning outside of comedic duos, referring to someone who is heterosexual.